# How to define a function in functional programming?

Tags: python, lambda, functional-programming, lambda-calculus

I am trying to learn Functional Programming, and I am doing so with Python. An exercise I am trying do is to make a function that returns true if a number is even.

```
def evenOrOdd(x):
return lambda x: x%2 == 0

print(evenOrOdd(1))
print(evenOrOdd(2))
print(evenOrOdd(3))
print(evenOrOdd(4))
<function evenOrOdd.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f7a9a145670>
<function evenOrOdd.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f7a9a145670>
<function evenOrOdd.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f7a9a145670>
<function evenOrOdd.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f7a9a145670>
```

This is what I have at the moment, but as you see, it is not returning a boolean.

Comment: `return x % 2 == 0`, if you really want to use lambda you have to call it: `return (lambda x: x % 2 == 0)(x)` but there is no need to use that

Comment: Just to expand on what @Matiiss writes.  You've created a function `evenOrOdd` that returns a function that tells you whether your initial value is even or odd.

Comment: I'm not sure what the lambda is supposed to achieve. Functional programming does use functions that return other functions, but there's no obvious point to such a pattern here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either do this: (declaring a normal function)

```py
def evenOrOdd(x):
    return x%2 == 0
```

or this: (declaring a function using a lambda)

```
evenOrOdd = lambda x: x%2 == 0
```

This

```py
def evenOrOdd(x):
    return lambda x: x%2 == 0
```

means you are returning a lambda function from the function `evenOrOdd`. In this case the variable x makes no actual difference, since the lambda redefines it. You could call it like so:

```py
evenOrOdd(999)(2) #999 could be anything
```

Comment: `lambda` defines a completely new `x` for its own scope

Comment: @Matiss Yeah thats what I meant by saying redefine, but your explanation is more correct

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an explicit function

```
def evenOrOdd1(x):
   return x%2 ==0
```

with lambda statement:

```
evenOrOdd2 = lambda x: x%2 ==0
```

then you can call with
print(evenOrOdd1(1))
print(evenOrOdd2(1))

but in both cases the names aren clear, I sugges using as names
`isEven` or  `isOdd` (because youre asking: is `evenOrOdd`? and the function anwer `True` or `False`, that's not very clear)

so

```
isEven = lambda x: not x%2
isOdd  = lambda x: x%2
```

#you only have to define one then you coud do

```
if isEven(x):
    doSomething

if not isEven(): #then it's Odd
    doSomethingElse
```